# Páginas de consultas com JPA

Tags: java, sql, jsf, hibernate

Estou alterando o código de uma consulta, pois a mesma retornará muitos dados quando o banco de dados estiver bem populado. Estou paginando a consulta. O problema é que quando implementaram ela, fizeram da seguinte maneira:

Recebe uma string, e é feita todas as combinações possíveis com ela, por exemplo a frase: "*teste teste2 teste3 teste4*", gera umas 15 strings e ele realiza 15 selects. Uma consulta eu sei como paginar, utilizando

```java
query.setFirstResult(inicioPagina);

query.setMaxResults(tamanhoDaPagina);
```

o problema surge quando são varias consultas.

------------------*Solução*-------------------------------------------
Consegui Resolver o problema aki :D

então o problema surgiu quando efetuei o cadastro de mais de 50mb na base de dados, e começou a dar uns problemas de memória no servidor, a solução que criei foi enves das consultas retonarem o Objeto Inteiro, retornam apenas o ID, e no final seleciono apenas os IDS da pagina e faço a consulta apenas da página

Comment: Por que motivo voce faz 15 selects? Nao pode ser um select, com 15 condicoes no where?

Comment: Então, o problema que os selects são strings com a condição Like "%string%". eu tentei fazer a consulta e pelo que estudei , não é possivel parece

Comment: Não sei qual banco de dados você está usando, mas é perfeitamente possível fazer "and (field like '%string%' or field like '%string2%')", apesar de achar que uma consulta destas traria problemas de performance. Nestes casos, é melhor usar alguma solução de busca "full text", como Apache Lucene.

Answer (score 1):

Uma questão importante é: **há um nível de prioridade entre as combinações da frase?** Por exemplo: resultados que são exatamente como a String original devem vir primeiro.

Se não houver priorização quanto à semelhança com a frase original, por exemplo, no caso dos resultados serem ordenados por algum outro valor como uma data ou número, então ao invés de realizar os `N` *selects* você poderia estruturar uma *query* dinâmica com as `N` cláusulas para realizar apenas uma consulta. Dessa forma, a limitação de resultados iria funcionar sem problemas.

Outra alternativa que permitiria priorizar certas combinações, é usar uma *query* nativa com um `N` *selects* unidos com `UNION`.

Exemplo:

```sql
SELECT ... FROM TABELA WHERE CAMPO LIKE '%frase 1%'
UNION
SELECT ... FROM TABELA WHERE CAMPO LIKE '%frase 2%'
UNION
SELECT ... FROM TABELA WHERE CAMPO LIKE '%frase 3%'
(...)
```

Assim teríamos primeiro os resultados da "frase 1", depois da "frase 2", etc.